# CakePHP GET action working, POST action is not working

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a ordercontroller where following action is defined:

```
class OrdersController extends AppController {
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'PhpExcel');
  
  public function payment_pb () {
    $this->log('Test the debug functionality with cakelog', 'debug');
  }

  public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('*');

    if ($this->action == 'payment_pb') {
      $this->log($this->request->method(), 'debug');
      $this->log($this->request, 'debug');
    }
  }
}
```

If I do a GET request I get following output:

> [datetime] Debug: GET
>
> [datetime] Debug: CakeRequest Object ([params] => ..., ... )
>
> [datetime] Debug: Test the debug functionality with cakelog

Everything is fine, I get the right debug output. If I try the POST request, I get following output:

> [datetime] Debug: POST
>
> [datetime] Debug: CakeRequest Object ([params] => ..., ... )

So there it's like the "payment_pb" is never reached in my Controller if I go to it via a POST request although it's definately going trough the correct functions before it has to go tot the correct action.

Do I have to do something special to my routhings to get this working? Any configuration I have to look at specificaly?

**EDIT: Security component issue**

I will add the code I've written for the Security component, the problem lays somewhere into this part of the code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $helpers = array('Html');
  public $components = array(
    'Security',
    'Session',
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
      'authorize' => array(
        'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
      ),
      'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'users' ,
        'action' => 'create' ,
      ) ,
      'logoutAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'users' ,
        'action' => 'logout' ,
      ),
      'authError' => 'You don't have sufficient permissions to enter this page',
    ),
  );

  function beforeFilter() {
    $this->_setupSecurity();
  }

  function _setupSecurity() {
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = '_badRequest';
    if (Configure::read('forceSSL')) {
      $this->Security->requireSecure('*');
    }
  }

  function _badRequest($type) {
    if (Configure::read('forceSSL') && !$this->request->is('ssl')) {
      $this->_forceSSL();
    }
    exit;
  }

  function _forceSSL() {
    $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
    exit;
  }
}
```

And my core.php file:

```
Configure::write('forceSSL', true); // OR Configure::write('forceSSL', false); WHEN on my testserver.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SSL on your server? Misconfiguration of SSL might cause this. I had experienced this before.

**EDIT: Suggestion for your SSL setup**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   if(Configure::read('forceSSL')){
      if(!$this->request->is('ajax')){ //just add this so that there will be no conflicts in your ajax calls regarding SSL
          $secured_pages=array("login", "add"); //just add here the actions you need to be secured

          if((!in_array($this->action, $secured_pages) && env('HTTPS')){
             $this->unforceSSL();
          }

          if(in_array($this->action, $secured_pages) && !env('HTTPS')) {
             $this->forceSSL();
          }
      }
   }
 }

public function unforceSSL() {
   return $this->redirect('http://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
}

public function forceSSL() {
   return $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
}
```

In this way it will be much easier and you can specify the secured pages only. It will be more efficient. You can remove the Security component. I tried Using Security component once but its not versatile enough to my project. So I did this one.

Comment: Yes, I have SSL Configurations set. Do I have to doublecheck the security component?

Comment: I've commented the Security component and the appropriate functions/functionalities... and right there, that's my problem! :) I will edit my original post to be more specific on the problem.

Comment: Thx for the sollution, the security component is still an alien thing to me :)